# Taunt icons for individual chartarcter

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When I'm asked to taunt a group of bad guys, I'm not sure what I should be doing.

I couldn't find any icon that does that, there is a default icon to it or it's per unit type?

One breed crumb would be awesome, or even pictures.

Comment: What class are you playing?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't played in a long time, but according to [torhead](http://www.torhead.com/ability/e0U4Adh/taunt) the following is the Taunt icon and description of the ability:

[image: taunt icon and description]

You may need to look through your skills to see if you have this ability or not.  The [swtor wiki](http://swtor.wikia.com/wiki/Taunt) also has some more descriptions about the Taunt ability and about taunting others.